# Way to not display webpage in Internet Explorer until after javascript is allowed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a simple page that displays text and various formatted elements and also a photo gallery. The photo gallery has a horizontal scrollbar beneath a larger image. The scroll area contains thumbnails that are loaded into the larger image area after they are clicked on. This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

However, in Internet Explorer the JavaScript is blocked initially and the user must allow it to run. Prior to the JavaScript being allowed by the user the page is displayed in the background but the formatting for the photo gallery is incorrect because it relies upon the currently blocked JavaScript (the larger images that are currently hidden are displayed down the page and it looks bad). Is there a workaround where I do not display the webpage at all until after the JavaScript is unblocked or perhaps another easy solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>    

 <title>index</title>        
 <style type="text/css">    
  body {            
        /*font-size:12px; modify this within each element*/
    }

 #wrapper {
    width:950px;
    height:800px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border-top:2px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom:2px solid #bbb;
    border-right:5px solid #000000;
    border-left:5px solid #000000;
    padding:0px;
    }

#topwrap {      
    width:950px;
    height:50px;
    }        

#topturqsq {      
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#7ECCC0;
    }

#topartdeco{     
    float:left;
    width:698px;
    height:48px;
    background-color:#FA8072;
    padding:1px;                            
}

#aptname{
    float:left;
    width:248px;
    height:149px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
    vertical-align:top;    
}

#contactbanner{    
    float:left;
    width:690px;
    height:29px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:right;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;     
}

#photogallery{
    width:698px;
    height:555px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
    float:left;                         
}

#maintext{      
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;   
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:10;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:top;
    position:relative;          
}    

a{
    display:block;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;    
}          

#leftnav{
    position:relative;
    width:248px;
    height:600px;
    font-size:20px; 
    float:left;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;             
}

#leftwrap{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:249px;
    height:750px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;        
}   

#linkDiv{       
    width:698px;
    height:120px;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
    padding-top:15px;    
}

#divLinks{              
    float:left;             
}    
#container1,#container2,#container3,#container4,#container5,#container6,#container7,#container8{        
    width:500px;
    height:375px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left:95px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;            
}   

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
// From: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?266743-Switch-Div-Content-Using-Javascript&p=1229155#post1229155

function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>          

<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="topwrap">                    
        <div id="topturqsq">

        </div>

        <div id="topartdeco">               
            <img src="images/artdeco.png" width="349" align="left"> <img src="images/artdeco.png" width="349" align="right">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="leftwrap">
        <div id="aptname">
            <img style="position:relative; top:15px; left:0px;"  src="images/banner.png" width="248" >

        </div>
        <div id="leftnav">

            <ul>        
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Amenities</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Nearby</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Lease</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Contact US</a></li> <br>
            <li><span  style="text-align:center;display:block;text-decoration:underline">Floor Plans </span></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">2 Bedroom</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">1 Bedroom</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Corporate</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" style="text-align:center;">Efficiency</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactbanner">
        <img src="images/phone.png" height="20" > Call us: (555) 555 - 5555 

    </div>
    <div id="photogallery">

        <div id="divLinks">
            <div id="container1"><img src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container2"><img src="images/Desert.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container3"><img src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container4"><img src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container5"><img src="images/Koala.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container6"><img src="images/Lighthouse.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container7"><img src="images/Penguins.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>
            <div id="container8"><img src="images/Tulips.jpg" width="500" height="375" border="1"></div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() { showDiv('1'); }
        </script>
        <div id="linkDiv">
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('1')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('2')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Desert.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('3')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('4')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('5')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Koala.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('6')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Lighthouse.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('7')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Penguins.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('8')"  style="display:inline"><img src="images/Tulips.jpg" width="120" height="90"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="maintext">
    <strong>heading</strong>

<blockquote>bunch of text</blockquote>

    </div>                      
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in theory you could `* { display:none; }` to hide *everything*, then bring it back when JS is accepted.. assuming that version of IE supports the wildcard (`*`) in CSS.

**Update**: Since you're doing this with the header.. I'm just going ot assume it has an ID of header..

```
<div id="header" style="display:none;">CONTENT</div>
<script type="text/javacript">
  window.onload = function(){ 
    var h = document.getElementById('header');
        h.style.display = 'block'; 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Everything is in the body. So `body { display:none; }`. Or directly in the html `<body style="display:none">`.

Comment: That too. Probably more effective/less load.

Comment: Thanks kcdwayne.  I'll try that.  Exactly where would I place {display:none;} and then display change this once javascript is accepted?  I'm assuming the display:none would go at the start of the body and then a modification display: property would go within the javscript that must be accepted??

Comment: I placed display:none; in the header in the css for body.  It now does not display anything, as expected.  How do I undo this once my conditions (javascript is running) are met so that the page loads?

Comment: `window.onload(function(){document.getElementByID('header').style.display = 'block'})`

Comment: Thanks kc, but I am very dense as I've only started with html, css, and javascript 1 week ago.  Can you please write a simple code where you explicitly tell me where to place the above code and also the initial display:none; that hides?  As of now, I have the code you pasted inside of a javascript that is in the header, but nothing is happening (it never turns display back on).  I do not know enough write now to effectively debug these things.

Comment: Updated code. Used to jquery now forgot correct call for `onload`

Comment: Be careful with applying this to the full page. It's better to style all the contents of your page to look reasonable disabled JS situations. Than use the techniques in this answer to enhance the page for users that have JS. Think about what happens if your user doesn't have a choice, doesn't understand the "You should switch on JS" message, or has JS turned off for it's own reasons? You'll be hiding valid content. Better less nice styled than none! Right?

Comment: Thanks, all caps. I do not know how to make a photo gallery without using javascript, however.  I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @SethMyers I'm not sure what you've got going on, but here are a few pieces of advice.. Using `ID` is generally a bad idea, unless it's 100% unique and you must assign many styles or a unique functionality to it. Otherwise, you should really use classes, as they can be repeated. You can only have 1 of each unique ID, ∞ classes. As far as a gallery, there are plenty of 'plug-ins' you can start with. Eventually you may find it's easier just to program the javascript/jquery to make it happen, but you can save a lot of trouble by reading up on best practices and really learning OOP. *- my 2 cents*